# Using either a single entry in an array changes result compared to using just a float variable

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I'm coding with python2 and trying to convert cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates. Originally I did not care about the original x and y values and so saved over them in every loop of my calculation, but now I want to save them and writing them to an array changes my results that I've produced using the angles array (no other code has been changed). I've written out a small excerpt from my code. Does anyone know what could be causing this and if so, which of these two pieces of code is producing more accurate angles (it seems to be affecting that array noticeably more, is it the arctan?)

Before:

```
no_pixels = 110
pixel_centre = np.array([55,55])
k=0
coords = np.zeros(no_pixels**2)
angles = np.zeros(no_pixels**2)
for i in range(0, no_pixels):
    for j in range(0, no_pixels):
        x = i - centre[0]
        y = j - centre[1]
        coords[k] = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
        if x >= 0:
            angles[k] = np.arctan(y/x)
        else:
            angles[k] = np.arctan(y/x) + np.pi
        k += 1
```

After:

```
no_pixels = 110
pixel_centre = np.array([55,55])
k=0
coords = np.zeros(no_pixels**2)
angles = np.zeros(no_pixels**2)
x = np.zeros(no_pixels**2)
y = np.zeros(no_pixels**2)
for i in range(0, no_pixels):
    for j in range(0, no_pixels):
        x[k] = i - centre[0]
        y[k] = j - centre[1]
        coords[k] = np.sqrt(x[k]**2 + y[k]**2)
        if x[k] >= 0:
            angles[k] = np.arctan(y[k]/x[k])
        else:
            angles[k] = np.arctan(y[k]/x[k]) + np.pi
        k += 1
```

Comment: You never change `k`, you're always assigning to `angles[0]`.

Comment: That was just a mistake in writing it out for this question, I have now amended this in the question above